# Dynamic query to take input from user and do filtering from the database node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend, fixed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlaWl.png)**What I'm trying is fetching columns from the user to which the user entered, The Good thing is Columns are getting fetched and the bad thing is the columns that I had applied conditions are not working.Can anyone help me out? I want a query that works for the filter option as in many websites to filter any product or something.
     Newbie here!!!**

```
routes.post('/FilterCandidate',function(req,res){
   var fetchparameter={};
   var dynamicquery={author : req.user.username};
   if(req.user.username){
   if(req.body.ConsultantName){
       fetchparameter["ConsultantName"] =  req.body.ConsultantName;
     }
   if(req.body.Location){
      fetchparameter["Location"] =  req.body.Location;
     }
   if(req.body.JobRole){
  fetchparameter["JobRole"] =  req.body.JobRole;
     }
   if(req.body.Skills){
      fetchparameter["Skills"] =  req.body.Skills.split(',');
     }
   if(req.body.VisaStatus){
      fetchparameter["VisaStatus"] =  req.body.VisaStatus;
     } 
   if(req.body.BillingRate){
      fetchparameter["BillingRate"] =  req.body.BillingRate;
     }
   if(req.body.experience){
      fetchparameter["experience"] = req.body.experience;
     }
   if(req.body.jobtype){
      fetchparameter["jobtype"] = req.body.jobtype;
     }
   if(req.body.Availability){
      fetchparameter["Availability"] = req.body.Availability;
    }
   if(req.body.experience){
      fetchparameter["Salary"] = req.body.Salary;
   }
   if(req.body.Salarytype){
      fetchparameter["Salarytype"] = req.body.Salarytype;
   }
    }


 /* This below code for conditions is not working*/

for(var key in fetchparameter){
   if (key== "Salary" ){
     dynamicquery[key] =  {$gte :fetchparameter[key]};
          }
         if(key == "Skills"){
             dynamicquery [key] = {$in : fetchparameter[key]};
          }
         if(key == "experience"){
            dynamicquery[key] = {$gte :fetchparameter[key]};
          }
         else{
             dynamicquery[key] = fetchparameter[key];
             }
   } 
 console.log(dynamicquery);
    Candidate.aggregate([ {$match : dynamicquery }],(err,docs) =>{
       res.render('FilteredCandidate',{'Candidates' : docs});
       });
 });
```

This is what I'm getting output to refer to the attached image

Comment: Please enter your error message as text so that others searching for your problem in the future can find your question on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should make a match object array it will make your code more neat and hoping that it will solve your problem

Ex:

```
var match = {$and:[]};
if(any condition satisfy){
match.$and.push({}) //condition
}
```

and most important do check if match.$and array must not be empty if it is then delete match.$and. this procedure will help you to maintain your query better provides more flexibility.

Comment: actually, when it is checking for the condition, the condition is treated as an object, please refer to the attached screenshot of the output.

Comment: because you made it a key value pair which is type object  so above explanation wil solve your problem even if you want me give a proper example i can covert your query into the suggested one

Comment: hey if it worked for you then either mark the answer accepted or edit the question and add tag solved in it might help others as well!